# Windows FTP client with SOCKS support

Tags: deployment, proxy, ftp

Does anybody know of a Windows FTP client with SOCKS support?

I need it to build  a deployment script... I tried Filezilla but its command-line support seems quite poor, I need something completely non-interactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I just found out that cURL supports FTP upload.